# Issue setting up MySql connection from java

Tags: java, mysql, maven

In Netbeans 11.1, I am trying to connect my Java Maven code to a MySql Database but every time I try setting up a connection based on internet tutorials I am getting errors. I have mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar in the Dependencies folder. I am very new to java and my Senior Project teammates are having issues figuring out the connection as well.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

//connect to DB
    private final String ConnectionString = "jdbc:mysql://54.235.42.66:3306/CIS470db";
    private final String UserName = "team6";
    private final String Password = "CIS470team6";
   //next line has error
 private final DBConnect dbConnect;
    //next line has error
    dbConnect = new DBConnect(ConnectionString, UserName, Password);
```

first error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DBConnect

### location: class NewJFrame

Second error:
 expected

cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DBConnect

### location: class NewJFrame

Comment: Where is the import for `DBConnect` ?

Comment: Also is this in a code block?

Comment: not too sure, Didn't quite learn the deffinition of a code block in school. and I pulled the DBConnect from a sample code I found but it obviously isn't working. So I need some help with connecting to the MYSQL DB somehow.

Comment: Move `dbConnect = new DBConnect(ConnectionString, UserName, Password);` to your constructor or other relevant method

Comment: Let me change something here based on this website.
https://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database

```Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionString, UserName, Password);```

from this I get the following
```unreported exception SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown.```

Answer (score 0):

You have not imported `DBConnect` in your class which is why the compiler does not know where to find `DBConnect` or what it even is.

You also need to do this otherwise it will result in a `SQLException`:

```
try {
    dbConnect = new DBConnect(ConnectionString, UserName, Password);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

Also, try to implement [Singleton Pattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-singleton-design-pattern-practices-examples/) when connecting with Database. It makes it really convenient to follow.

Here's how I did it in one of my older projects:

**DatabaseConnection.java**

```
package com.stackoverflow.utility;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.stackoverflow.constant.Credentials;

public class DatabaseConnection implements Credentials {
    private static DatabaseConnection database;
    Connection connection;

    public static DatabaseConnection getDatabase() {
        if (database == null) {
            database = new DatabaseConnection();
        }

        return database;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        if (connection == null || connection.isClosed()) {
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PWD);
        }

        return connection;
    }
}
```

**CloseConnection.java**

```
package com.stackoverflow.utility;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class CloseConnection {
    public static void close(ResultSet resultSet) {
        if (resultSet != null) {
            try {
                resultSet.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void close(PreparedStatement preparedStatement) {
        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            try {
                preparedStatement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void close(Connection connection) {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void close(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, ResultSet resultSet) {
        close(resultSet);
        close(preparedStatement);
    }
}
```

**Credentials.java**

```
package com.stackoverflow.constant;

public interface Credentials {
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"; // Database driver
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://116.72.10.78:3352/MohitDB"; // Database url

    // Database credentials
    static final String USER = "user";
    static final String PWD = "password";
}
```

**Queries.java**

```
package com.stackoverflow.constant;

public interface Queries {
    public static final String AUTHENTICATION_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM TableUser WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
}
```

**Authentication method**

```
public boolean getAuthentication(Login login) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = DatabaseConnection.getDatabase().getConnection()
                .prepareStatement(AUTHENTICATION_QUERY);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, login.getUsername());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, login.getPassword());

        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        if (resultSet.next()) {
            close(preparedStatement, resultSet);

            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```